# How to append an object value and get the content?

Tags: html, angular

```
<div *ngFor="let emp of employees">
 <p [innerText]="content.employees +'.'+ emp + '.name'"></p>
</div>
```

The above code prints like
    ***[object Object].emp.name***

But i want it to print the value of object '**content.employees.emp.name**'

Comment: Wouldn't it be content.employees[emp][name] ?

Comment: what is content.employees?

Comment: Great that worked.. gave like content.employees[emp].name